# Group By issue - Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

My table looks like this (and I'm using MySQL):

```
id      NewID   SenderID    ReceiverID  msg     msgType         TimeStamp
1       5       9           8           dfdf    1           7-03-2021 6:10 AM
2       4       9           8           dfdf    1           7-03-2021 6:11 AM
3       3       9           8           dfdf    1           7-03-2021 6:13 AM
4       5       9           8           fgdf    1           7-03-2021 6:16 AM
```

My target is to take id (_maxid) highest record to be on top in table, removing any duplicate record if that exists.

I m running following query,

```
  SELECT    MAX(id) _maxid , NewID 
          FROM      tb_detail
          GROUP BY  id order by id desc
```

and it returns this-

```
_maxid      NewID
4           5
3           3
2           4
1           5
```

Expected result:

```
_maxid      NewID
4           5
3           3
2           4
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you group by `id`, if you want maximum per `newID`?

Comment: That brings another issue in that whole scenario. changes the sequence in very odd way.

_maxid NewID     
3  3
2  4
4  5

Comment: What's the version of mysql you are using?

Comment: `order by 1 desc`. Try to read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) first.

Comment: Also if you are using MySQL, then please do not add tags of other DBMSes, because they're not relevant

Comment: @astentx - That helps!  ```order by 1 desc ``` has brought me the result needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

```
create table tb_detail(id int,      NewID int,   SenderID    int,ReceiverID  int,msg varchar(10),     msgType         int, TimeStamp timestamp);
insert into tb_detail values(1,       5   ,    9,           8   ,        'dfdf',    1  ,'2021-7-03 6:10');
insert into tb_detail values(2 ,      4  ,     9 ,          8  ,         'dfdf' ,   1  ,  '2021-7-03 6:11');
insert into tb_detail values(3  ,     3 ,      9  ,         8 ,          'dfdf'  ,  1 ,  '2021-7-03 6:13');
insert into tb_detail values(4   ,    5,       9   ,        8,           'fgdf'   , 1,    '2021-7-03 6:16');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select max(id) _maxid,newid from tb_detail
group by newid
order by max(id) desc;
```

| _maxid | newid |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)